# ¿Como funcionan los array de mi carrito?

Tags: php, mysqli

Podrían explicarme cómo funcionan los `array` de mi carrito, por qué se necesita de varios tipos de `array` diferentes para agregar productos a la cesta de compra.

He buscado la documentación en PHP, he logrado comprender con los ejemplos que se muestran, pero comprendería mucho mejor una breve explicación tomando como ejemplo mi código :)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('db.php');
    $status="";

    if (isset($_POST['code']) && $_POST['code']!=""){
        $code = $_POST['code'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `code`='$code'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $name = $row['name'];
        $code = $row['code'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $image = $row['image'];

        $cartArray = array(
            $code=>array(
                'name'=>$name,
                'code'=>$code,
                'price'=>$price,
                'quantity'=>1,
                'image'=>$image
            )
        );

        if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $cartArray;
            $status = "<div class='box'>¡El producto se agrego al carrito!</div>";
        } else {
            $array_keys = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            if(in_array($code,$array_keys)) {
                $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>¡El producto ya está añadido a su carrito!</div>";
            } else {
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = array_merge($_SESSION["shopping_cart"],$cartArray);
                $status = "<div class='box'>¡El producto se agrego al carrito!</div>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo siguiente corresponde a un [ARRAY ASOCIATIVO](https://diego.com.es/arrays-asociativos-en-php) `Los arrays asociativos son arrays cuyos keys son strings personalizados. Para acceder a los valores de un array asociativo se hace de la misma forma que con arrays numéricos, mediante corchetes`

```
$code=>array(
                'name'=>$name,
                'code'=>$code,
                'price'=>$price,
                'quantity'=>1,
                'image'=>$image
            )
```

Entonces en tu código tienes un array de nombre `cartArray` que contiene un array asociativo con el valor de `$code`, que a su vez tiene otro array asociativo con los valores devueltos por la consulta de base de datos.

```
        $cartArray = array( 

            $code=>array(
                'name'=>$name,
                'code'=>$code,
                'price'=>$price,
                'quantity'=>1, #valor por defecto en duro, siempre es uno
                'image'=>$image
            )
        );
```